# How to remove CODE parameter from AZURE function API url?

Tags: azure, function, api, parameters

I am new in AZURE. I have created multiple functions in AZURE with API URL. Some function contains API URL with CODE parameter and some are without CODE parameter.
Can any one let me know how to remove the CODE parameter from the API URL?
e.g

```
1) With paramter: API_URL?code=oxwOFsfARhzBZpworHGR9cKeN/Mns0L6s4daqQuJft8ui84yYdbOfQ==
2) Without parameter: API_URL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just set the `authLevel` to `anonymous`:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-3.0.9",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "YOUR-DLL",
  "entryPoint": "YOUR-ENTRY-POINT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Azure Function Proxies - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

That should help with presenting a "friendly URL".